# I'm trying to do an icon in HTML for a social media website I'm building.. How do I create a free-standing icon?

Tags: html, css, icons

I basically want an image as a button, for example, see the 'recent inbox messages' thing at the top next to stack Exchange? I want to recreate that moreorless but with my own image.. How would I go about doing this, I've tried:

```
<button type="button" name="test">
  <img src="C:/Trey/rs-logo.jpeg">
</form>
```

but that didn't work, could anyone help (sorry if I worded all of this badly, English [though my native language] isn't a strong point!

-Trey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an image button with something like this:

```
<a href="#">
   <img src="yourImage.png">
</a>
```

This creates an image element with an anchor surrounding it, so for all intents and purposes, it's an "image button." You will have to style it to your liking.

**UPDATE**

Your code will also work if you change it to

```
<button>
   <img src="yourImage.png">
</button>
```

You have to close the button tag. This will create an ugly-looking button with an image in it, but you can use CSS to style it to your liking.

Comment: Will accept this when it allows me! Thank you so much! that seems so obvious now! hahah thanks :)

Comment: No problem :). I know that when I first started with HTML, I had noooo idea what I was doing. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you are opening a button and closing a form which is not even opend yet
you should use  in first place. how ever using an image as a button is not the best idea i guess

```
<button type="button" name="test">
        <img src="C:/Trey/rs-logo.jpeg"/>
</button>
```

made you a quick fiddle to check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/T2JRt/1/

Comment: Thanks! Would vote up but my rep isn't high enough but thank you!